# understanding filestream

Tags: c#

Right now I'm writing file to the disk using this approach

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileOne, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (StreamWriter streamW = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
    {
       streamW .Write("Blah");
       streamW.Close();
    }
    fileStream .Close();
}
```

How can I write more files, for example fileTwo inside this using statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I write more files, for example fileTwo inside this using statement?

You'd need to open a different stream. Each `FileStream` will only write to a single file. It's not clear whether you want to write to two files *at a time*, or write one file after another. In the latter case, you might just want a loop. For example:

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    // Note: File.CreateText is simpler than creating a FileStream then
    // wrapping it in a StreamWriter
    using (TextWriter writer in File.CreateText(file))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need your `Close` calls - the fact that you've got appropriate `using` statements means `Dispose` will be called automatically, which is basically equivalent to `Close`.

Comment: +1. on `using` - there is a good chance that by now people us it as [Cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)... as result `.Close` and even `.Dispose` calls inside of using :(